# Where will a H+ attack on 6-hydroxyhexan-2-one?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, reactivity, electronegativity

Where will a H+ attack on 6-hydroxyhexan-2-one? Protonation can take place either on the ketone or the alcohol. So where will it attack? In short, on which of the two oxygen atoms is electron density higher?

[image: 6-hydroxyhexan-2-one]

Comment: Well,what do you think?

Comment: As a hint, consider which lone pair is more "free" i.e. less tightly bound to the oxygen nucleus

Comment: You mean on alcohol?

Comment: Yep.. If you have understood why... Then you have your answer

Comment: Please note that the site of preferred protonation may not be the one that leads to reactivity. Since proton transfer between heteroatoms is very fast, you are operating under Curtin-Hammett kinetics, so the more reactive intermediate (regardless of its concentration) will be the one that reacts.

Comment: Well put @Zhe! This is not an either/or situation. I hope Franshu isn't under the misapprehension that protonation occurs at only one of the two oxygens. In CH3OH/H+ this hydroxyketone will lead to the cyclic, pyran mixed ketal (and/or 2-methyl dihydropyran) whose mechanism of formation requires protonation of the ketone oxygen.